# How to find out if a set of Resque jobs have finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, jobs

I have the following code:

```
[23, 45, 69, 20].each do |page_id|
  Resque.enqueue(ProcessPage, page_id)
end
```

I would like to know when all those jobs have finished processing to notify the user via email. My first attempt was to notify the user at the very end of the job, but that would work just individually for each job.

I have found this gem [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status), which basically let's you do this:

```
job_ids = []
[23, 45, 69, 20].each do |page_id|
  job_ids << ProcessPage.create(page_id)
end
```

And then you can check the status of a job by doing:

```
status = Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id)
```

What confuses me is... When should I do that checking for all the statuses? I mean, would I be doing a while checking the status of all the jobs? That would make the server to timeout, any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: you would use ajax or something like that

Comment: @phoet What do you mean? How often would I do the AJAX call and why it for? I need to notify the User by email.

Comment: you did not write that in your question. you could start another job for checking the status.

Comment: phoet, so I would have another job with a "loop" just checking until all the status for those jobs_id are "finished"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to paste any code here because it looks like you're pretty familiar with how jobs should be written but think about the following idea:

You should have a resque job which gets and array of ids to process.
This resque jobs creates a single resque job for each of the ids so they will be processed in parallel.
After creating the resque jobs for specific ids it will create another resque jobs which gets the list of ids and periodically checks on them to see if they're finished. When they're done, this job will send the user an email.

With this paradigm you enjoy all of the worlds:

1. Each ID has its own job.
2. Parallel execution.
3. Status check is done on the background thus the user won't get timeout.

UPDATE:

A pseudo code for the check resque job:

```
class CheckerJob
  @queue = :long

  def self.perform(ids)
    finished = []
    while finished.size < ids.size
      ids.each do |id|
        finished << id if job_finished?(id)
      end
      sleep 10
    end
    send_email_to_user
  end
end
```

Now all you left to do is to implement both `job_finished?(id)` and `send_email_to_user` methods.

Comment: Alright. This makes sense, but when you say periodically, what do you mean? Can you write how that "checker" job would look like?

Comment: Thanks. When you say parallel execution, that depends on how many workers I have right? What do you think about using Multithreading paradigm in this case?

Comment: I'd go with separate workers. This way you have more control over the tasks - you can see them running on the UI.

Comment: There is a problem with this code. When we do ``` if job_finished?(id) ``` since we are doing for all the ids, for a job that has finished, we will be checking it more than once, and fill finished wrongly.

Comment: Instead of `ids.each` do `(ids-finished).each`

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution would be to have your job take a list of ids:

```
Class Job
  def self.perform(ids)
    threads = ids.inject([]) do |memo, id|
      memo << Thread.new { # whatever }
    end
    ThreadsWait.join_all(*threads)
    # All threads are done
    # Notify user that job is finished
  end
end
```

Don't have a job that checks whether this one has finished. If you're going to go that kind of route, subscribe to Redis events http://redis.io/topics/internals-rediseventlib

**UPDATE**: added multithreading

Comment: If I follow this approach I would have a job that would do "X" jobs. That would make that "Parent" job extremly slow, as each of my "children" jobs take quite a while...

Comment: Can you explain further? I mean, what it comes to my mind is that in your ```ìds.each do |id| #Create a new job for this particular id ``` but then I have the same problem. I don't know when all are finished.

Comment: I am completely new to multithreading paradigm. That would mean that a worker could do "X" jobs in parallel? Also, I think Resque is single threaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
Resque.enqueue_to("page_processes#{user.id}", ProcessPage, page_id)

#code in ProcessPageWorker below
def self.perform(page_id, user_id)
  #work
  # code below notifies user if the 'page_processes' queue is equal to 1
  notify_user if Resque.size("page_processes#{user_id}") == 1
end
```

We enqueue the job in a queue named 'page_processes' plus the user's ID. Once every job is done, we check the size of the "page_processes#{user_id}" queue. If the queue is equal to 1, it would mean that the job being worked on is the last job in the queue so we should notify the user. We include the user_id in the name of the queue to ensure the queue's unique name.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, but would I have a "named" queue for each User that wants to use the API?

Comment: Yes, you would have a named queue so you could refer to that queue later on and check its size(the number of jobs pending). I updated my answer to include user's id in the name of the queue so that each user has its own queue.